# Journée des femmes et filles de science

Tags: usage

Le 11 février est la
« Journée internationale des femmes et des filles de science », selon l’ONU.

Dans mon entourage, principalement composé d’anglophones, j’essaie d’expliquer pourquoi cette expression « fille de science » me semble très peu heureuse.

J’ai dit, pour faire simple, que « fille » renvoie, dans le sens courant, à la parenté : on est « fille de quelqu’un ».
J’ai dit aussi que l’on ne dirait pas « garçon de science » ou « fils de science ».
Enfin, il y a beaucoup d’expressions péjoratives utilisant « fille ».

Voyez-vous d’autres façons simples de faire comprendre cela à des non francophones ? Ma perception est-elle fautive ?

Comment: Ça aurait pu être pire. On a échappé à la *Journée internationale des femmes et des demoiselles de science...* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Oui :-) Je retiens l'idée de demoiselle !

Comment: Le contexte: The UN says: International Day of Women and Girls **in** Science. L'idée c'est que les femmes de par le passé étaient éxclues de la science, ainsi que les filles. L'erreur porte sur "de science". On est obligé en français de dire ici: dans le domaine de la science ou dans le domaine scientifique ou en science ou dans les sciences.

Comment: C'est l'UNESCO qui fait partie de l'ONU. Pardon.

Comment: On peut ajouter que l'UNESCO a son siège à Paris. Et que le français fait partie des langues officielles de l'organisation.

Comment: Et, de ce fait, l'expression « Journée internationale des femmes et des filles de science » est reprise telle quelle dans la communication institutionnelle de beaucoup d'universités francophones.

Comment: La traduction est malheureuse mais pas à cause des mots femmes et filles. Elles sont **12 millions de filles** mariées chaque année dans le monde avant l’âge de 18 ans. Si nous n’agissons pas maintenant, plus de 150 millions seront mariées d’ici à 2030 : c’est le message de la nouvelle étude publiée par l’ONG Plan International. https://www.plan-international.fr/news/2018-12-13-150-millions-de-filles-mariees-de-force-avant-2030-temps-agir

Comment: @Lambie I commend you for pointing out these issues. Had your comment been the only one you made in the Q&A, that would have been very strong imho, hinting maybe at a political component to the choice of words. You should have answered this imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, je trouve aussi la formulation étrange. J'imagine qu'on a eu peur d'exclure les élèves du primaire et du secondaire en n'utilisant que « femme », mais « fille de science » n'est pas très heureux, contrairement à « femme de science ».

Tu pourrais leur dire que ça donne une impression peut-être un peu similaire à :

> *International Day of Women and Damsels in Science.*

Quelques hypothétiques variantes : *Women and Fillies in science*, *Women and Lasses in science*, *Women and Daughters in science*, *Women and Chicks in science*...

@LukeSawczak suggested *Daughters of Science* that leads me to find this [drawing from Punch's Almanack](https://www.istockphoto.com/fr/vectoriel/illustrations-de-caricatures-britanniques-de-bande-dessin%C3%A9e-de-satire-filles-de-gm1147841326-309786899), 1899:

[image]

On peut aussi se dire que s'il s'était agi de la « Journée de l'homme et du garçon de science », l'effet n'aurait pas été meilleur. D'un côté, certains risquent de penser à « fille de joie » et de l'autre à « garçon de café »... et je ne parle même pas de l'effet de « Journée de l'homme et du fils de science ».

Comment: Women and chicks. Parfait : je crois que le côté péjoratif de l'expression est bien traduite !

Comment: "Daughters of Science" perhaps? Also, would "des filles et des femmes de science" have avoided the problem?

Comment: @LukeSawczak "des filles et des femmes" does not seem too nice either. "Fille" seems to be a word to use with care, except in a few precise sentences, like "Je suis la fille de M . X." or  "Mon nom de jeune fille est Dupont".

Comment: @LukeSawczak But "Daughters of science" is good to show my point.

Comment: @Denis Intéressant, merci. Je pense créer un autre fil pour m'éclairer ces points sur « fille »

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, un bon dessin est parfois mieux qu'une longue explication.

Comment: « fille » n'est pas du tout péjoratif dans ce contexte à moins d'être soi-même misogyne.

Comment: @gdupras Bien sûr, pour ceux qui sont misogynes, *Femmes de science* est déjà mal vu. Le problème vient pour moi plutôt de l'association *femmes* et *filles* qui est malvenue. On peut très bien être *femme* **et** *fille*, toute femme est d'ailleurs forcément la fille de quelqu'un. Comme l'a écrit l'OP, *Hommes et garçons* et encore moins *Homme et fils* n'auraient pas été mieux inspirés. Peut-être que cette perception n'est pas la même au Québec.

Comment: dans le domaine scientifique. "in science" n'est pas "de science". Voilà le problème. **Journée internationale des femmes et des filles  en science ou dans les sciences

Comment: @Lambie Tu traduis mieux *in science* mais *Homme de science* et *Femme de science* étant des expressions consacrées, le traducteur a du se sentir obligé de les utiliser. *Femme en science* ou *Femme dans les sciences* ne vont pas, *Femme dans le domaine scientifique* est lourd et *des femmes et des filles dans...* ne résout pas le problème du mot *fille* ici.

Comment: https://www.fetedelascience.fr/forum-les-femmes-en-science Les femmes en science. Of course, femme en science doesn't work. It has to be plural. Il n'y pas de problème avec le mot filles: Les femmes et les filles en science,

Comment: Le problème vient de "de science" et pas des mots femmes ou filles.

Comment: @Lambie *De science* est un détail accessoire. Le vrai problème posé par le nom de cette journée vient de *femmes et filles* et il aurait été présent aussi avec *hommes et garçons*. C'est *fille* qui ne colle pas avec le reste.

Comment: https://wwz.ifremer.fr/dyneco/Actualites/Archives-2018/Seminaire-Dyneco-d-Aurore-Regaudie-de-Gioux-12-02-18 Une meilleure traduction: Les Nations Unis ont déclaré le 11 février comme étant le Jour International de la Femme et de la Fille dans la Science afin de célébrer les efforts de la communauté pour engager les femmes et les filles en Science,

Comment: 11-févr. 15:00 60 Les femmes et filles en science Cécile Vrain https://www.carsat-auvergne.fr/files/live/sites/carsat-auvergne/files/PDF/actus-retraites/HappyVisio-programme-janv-juin_2021.pdf

Comment: On aurait dit « Journée internationale des femmes de science », cela m'aurait bien plu, à la fois sur la forme et sur le fond. Dans mon esprit, « femme de science » n'exclut pas les femmes jeunes faisant de la science.

Comment: _...des femmes scientifiques (de tous les âges)_. Sans doute un truc culturel, l'emploi me dérange moins que vous autres je pense, même si je le trouve pas trop heureux non plus.

Comment: @Lambie  Extrait de ton article « On les appelle les «missing women». Sur les bancs des écoles, dans les rues, dans les maternités, il manque des filles, des nièces, des cousines ».  La personne qui pose la question a une perception et trouve pas très heureuse la phrase, parce qu'il y a des emplois péjoratifs avec _fille_ en français. C'est une question en partie subjective et on veut voir si cette perception est ancrée dans la langue. On peut être d'accord ou non mais ça n'a rien à voir avec ton propos, franchement.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Il est logique que si on ne dit pas femmes et filles ou femmes et jeune filles, on est en train de bannir l'idée. Personellement, je trouve cela monstreux. Les mots fille et son analogue en anglais girl peuvent toujours s'associés à des "péjoratifs".

Comment: @Lambie Non, il n'est pas « logique » que ça implique de _bannir_ une idée. Mais est-ce une censure, une autocensure, et quel est l'impact de l'emploi ou du non emploi de tel ou tel mot sur la vie des gens, sur comment on les perçoit etc., ce sont des questions intéressantes. Il faut se les poser dans la vie.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134089/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-journee-des-femmes-et-filles-de-science).